# How to display the highest value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a condition that should display a single master if the report date is greater than or equal to its start date work. And based on this condition so that it works correctly (that is, exactly one master was displayed, not several), I added another condition that finds the highest value based on the previous condition, and one master should actually be displayed. But this condition does not work.     `if (Math.max(...this.masters.map(master => new Date(master.date_work).getTime()))){}`. And because of this, all wizards are displayed whose start date is less than the date reports. I can not understand why it does not work. Can  apply this sorting?

```
this.filteredMasters.push(master => master.date_work.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date_work).getTime() - new Date(a.date_work).getTime()))
```

But the data ceases to appear. I mean, the data is no longer displayed.

```
if (this.mastersService) {
  this.mastersService.fetch().subscribe(
    master => {
      this.filteredMasters = []
      this.masters = master
      for(let team of this.filteredTeams){
        for(let master of this.masters){
          if (master.teams_id == team.team_id) {
            if (new Date(master.date_work) <= (new Date(this.selectedRep4Hour.report_date))) {
              if (Math.max(...this.masters.map(master => new Date(master.date_work).getTime()))) {
                this.filteredMasters.push(master)
              }
            }                  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Dates of the beginning of the work of the masters can not be the same as the `date_work` field is unique.

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let team of filteredTeams">
  <div *ngFor="let master of filteredMasters">
    {{master.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will keep pushing all values in `this.filteredMasters` as you are putting `Math.max` in `if condition`. So, `if condition` will always be true because `Math.max` will always return some max value.

You can change your code in the given way:

```
if (this.mastersService) {
  this.mastersService.fetch().subscribe(
    master => {
      this.filteredMasters = []
      this.masters = master

      const maxValue = <Add some default MIN value>
      const maxMaster = <Add some default value>

      for(let team of this.filteredTeams){
        for(let master of this.masters){
          if (master.teams_id == team.team_id) {
            if (new Date(master.date_work) <= (new Date(this.selectedRep4Hour.report_date))) {
                // this.filteredMasters.push(master)
                const curr = Math.max(...this.masters.map(master => new Date(master.date_work).getTime()));
                if (maxValue < curr) {
                  maxValue = curr;
                  maxMaster = master;
                }
            }                  
          }
        }
        this.filteredMasters.push(maxMaster);
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Sure to to add a default value?

Comment: @user10720571 for `maxMaster` you can add default value which you want to be shown to each team. If you don't want to show any default value, then you can assign it null value or empty string (if it is string variable).

Comment: And by the way, I do not quite understand this condition                 `if (maxValue < curr) {
                  maxValue = curr;
                  maxMaster = master;
                } `

Comment: @user10720571 That condition is to change the `maxMaster` only when a new max value exists.